# Show that $A + (B + \Bbb N)$ is in bijective correspondence with $(\Bbb N + A) + B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $A + (B + \Bbb N)$ is in bijective correspondence with $(\Bbb N + A) + B$.
$A$ and $B$ are sets and $\Bbb N$ is set of natural numbers.

Also in my textbook it is written that A+B = A×{0} ∪ B×{1}

Comment: And + is?$\ \ \ \ $

Comment: What do you mean when you denote "addition" of sets.  Do you mean the *union of sets*?  If you mean union $\cup$ rather than addition (+), then both representations are equivalent, due to commutativity and associativity of $\cap$, i.e.  both contain exactly the same elements.

Comment: In my textbook its written A + B = A x {0} ∪ B x {1}

Comment: Just find how elements of both sets look like and then find q bijection. This should be straightforward